# O que significa while(x--) em linguagem C?

Tags: c, while

Me deparei com esse código e não entendi o laço `while(a--)`, o que significa?

```
int main(){
     char pisca[10], a = 3;
     short numero;

     while(a--){
         numero = 0;

         while(1){
             scanf("%s caw", pisca);

             if(!strcmp(pisca, "caw")) break;

             if(pisca[0] == '*') numero += 4;
             if(pisca[1] == '*') numero += 2;
             if(pisca[2] == '*') numero += 1;

         } 

         printf("%hd\n", numero);
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vamos começar pela expressão dentro do `while`: `a--` é o mesmo que `a = a - 1`.

Imagino que saiba o que o `while` faz. Toda vez que passar por ele executará aquela expressão, portanto a cada vez a variável `a` terá subtraído 1. Até chegar em 0.

O `while` executa enquanto é verdadeiro, ou sejam qualquer número que não seja 0. Quando chega em zero considera como false e, portanto, o laço deve ser encerrado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -2):

A condição implícita do while é "!= 0" o "a--" não está testando nada.